# Spring - There is already handler [com.application.myGoogleAppEngine.controller.MapController@978068] mapped

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've the following error. I don't understand why.

[INFO] javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot map handler [mapController] to URL path [/map.jsp]: There is already handler [com.application.myGoogleAppEngine.controller.MapController@978068] mapped.

Do you have any solutions ?

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app
    version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
             <servlet-class>
                 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
             </servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.application.myGoogleAppEngine.controller" />
    <bean id="helloBean" class="com.application.myGoogleAppEngine.HelloWorld">
    <property name="name" value="Mkyong" />
    </bean>

     <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
           <property name="defaultLocale" value="fr" />
     </bean>

     <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
           <property name="paramName" value="language" />
</bean>

     <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource"> 
          <property value="classpath:MessageBundle" name="basename"/> 
          <property value="UTF-8" name="defaultEncoding"/> 
     </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" name="viewClass"/>
        <property name="prefix">
          <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
          <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
     </bean>

 </beans>
```

IndexController.java

```
package com.application.myGoogleAppEngine.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index.jsp")
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView initForm(HttpServletResponse res){

            try{       
              PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
              out.println("Hello, world!");
              out.close();
            }
    catch(IOException ex){}

    return null;
    //return new ModelAndView("address");
  }
}
```

MapController.java:

```
package com.application.myGoogleAppEngine.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/map.jsp")
public class MapController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView initForm(HttpServletResponse res){

           try{       
                 PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
                 out.println("Hello, world!");
                 out.close();
           }
           catch(IOException ex){}  

            return null;
            //return new ModelAndView("address");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the following changes

In your XML, add annotation-driven element:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.application.myGoogleAppEngine.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

In web.xml, change the url pattern

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So, you can use your Controllers like that:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/map")
public class MapController {
    ...
}
```